# And then suddenly, click / went her face into a look of almost seraphic calm. Is it inversion?

Tags: grammar

It came from the novel Matilda.

And then suddenly, click
went her face into a look of almost seraphic calm.

Is this sentence inversion ?

I searched the inversion on the google and I found several cases when inversion is used

but there was no case like above

Comment: [I searched for, but better is: I looked for ]

Comment: As in [*Pop Goes the Weasel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_Goes_the_Weasel) (not *The Weasel Goes Pop*). Even ***kids*** know that one!

Comment: just started learn English..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed a stylistic inversion.  It has the verb of motion (went) which is being used metaphorically, and it is inverted.  It is exemplified on a [forum post](https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst36774_Stylistic-inversion.aspx#:%7E:text=a%20good%20pace.-,Bang%20went%20the%20starter%27s%20gun%20and%20the%20runners%20went%20off,the%20original%2C%20by%20the%20way.)

> The starter's gun went bang and the runners went off at a good pace.
>
> Bang went the starter's gun and the runners went off at a good pace.

Although you could go further and say

> Bang went the starter's gun, and off the runners went, at a good pace.

The purpose is to bring the short onomatopoeia "click" to head the phrase "click went her face", and give end weight to the longer "went her face"